# lex/bison compiling error after ubuntu 18.04 upgrade

Tags: g++, compiler-warnings, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to start the next phase of my compiler project and I get this error when compiling

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libfl.so: undefined reference to `yylex'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:82: recipe for target 'gpl' failed

i went back to previous phases, did a make clean and recompiled and none of it compiles now, same error (it did before). This happened after I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04. I checked for further upgrades afterwords to see if any of the required packages needed an update and there's none. Does anyone have any idea why this stopped working after the update? (possibly config file or something?)

Comment: Seems you are using gcc-7. Which gcc? version are you building ? ... Note : "flex legacy" is also available → `flex-old`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either link the static library (`libfl.a`) or use the `--as-needed` linker flag.